# How to configure and setup Xdebug in phpstorm for Magento?

Tags: magento2, php, debugging, xdebug

I want to use the debugger to debug my module but I don't know how to configure and set up  debugger in phpstorm, any hints or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this step to configure xdebug.

> 1:Run this command in terminal

```
sudo apt install php7.4-xdebug
```

after that check PHP version by this command and we will configure according to that xdebug version

```
PHP -v
```

[image]

in my case, Xdebug version is given v3 so that I will set it up accordingly

> 2: now run this command

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

and paste the following code in that file

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.client_port = 9003                    
xdebug.mode = debug
```

and remember in the first line /usr/lib/php/"your folder name"/xdebug.so
go this path and check what the folder number is and paste it according to in some cases it is different but mostly it is the same.

Here are the settings if your **Xdebug version is v2**

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
 xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
 xdebug.remote_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
 xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
 xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
 xdebug.remote_mode = req
 xdebug.remote_port = 9003
```

now restart apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

so far half our work is done now let's do some settings in phpstorm
open PHPstorm got to
**File>>Settings>>PHP>Xdebug**
and click on the
**validate**
a new window will open and in that window type your URL accordingly
and hit Validate

[image]

so far your Xdebug is configured in phpstorm,
and you can use breakpoint and turn on debug listener and hit that file and start using xdebug
in case any issues let me know, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow these steps :

Install X debug for the PHP version which you are using by this command :

```
sudo apt install php7.4-xdebug
```

In this file add these lines :

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.client_port = 9003                    
xdebug.mode = debug
```

Then install x debug extension from the google chrome.

Finally change the x debug port in the PHP storm in this way :

```
File>>Settings>>PHP>Xdebug
```

If you find any more problem then tell me we will resolve that also.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes When you try to validate it gives some error like invalid port or service not available etc
always make sure the port you set in that file and the port in your phpstorm is same, like in my case it is **90003**
and always **restart apache**
and if your xdebug is validated but still not working then try to use a **Xdebug Helper extension**

thats all, thanks